# is it possible to fetch data from multi dbs through one connection request

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I need to work on this poorly designed db where a new group of data are established by adding a new db to the server. So I have to fetch data from multi dbs, I wonder is there a way to get all thoes group data through one connection? I am using c#.

Comment: Could you specify the DB? How often is a new group added?

Comment: Which database server are you using? It is possible to set up a connection between database servers from the database in SQL Server and Oracle (and probably most database engines) - but setting it up will be different for each.

Comment: using sql server, the new group is added by calling stored procedure, and insert a new record in a table to keep track of the new db name.

Comment: This design is so bad it would lead me to seek other employment! It boggles my mind that anyone could have thought this was a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(aside: is it possible to influence the design? This sounds in part like what database schema names are designed for...)

It is sometimes possible (for example in SQL Server by using `database.schema.object` notation, or even `server.database.schema.object`), but I don't recommend it as the same approach won't fit all use-cases, and it breaks a lot of best-practice guidelines. I would strongly recommend simply generating the connection string per database, perhaps using [`DbConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), or more specific variants like [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

You could disable pooling on the dynamic connections if you are worried about having too many open (pooled) connections (but you would then need to handle connection management yourself; personally I'd be tempted to leave pooling enabled until I can prove there is a problem).

Comment: if generating connection string for each db, does that mean i have to create as many connections as the number of dbs? sounds kind of inefficient to me, there might be more than hundreds of groups.

Comment: Wow; hundreds of dbs? Yes... there is an inefficiency there, but I think that is in the *design*. You could **try** the database.schema.name approach, but at own risk...

Answer (score 0):

if all the databases are on the same server, you could just query them using the full name from a connection to whatever the main database is. You may need to build all code dynamically with this design though as you don't know in advance what database you need to connect to.

```
select * from database1.dbo.mytable m
join  database2.dbo.mytable m2 on m.id = m2.id
```